# Passing parameter with OnClick to Filemaker Using D3

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to pass a parameter when I click on a pie slice, that was created using the D3 library, with the following code to a Filemaker database script. The dataset is in an Array of Objects format.

```
var dataset = [{key: 1, amt: 5}, {key: 2, amt: 10}, {key: 3, amt: 20}];
```

I can can put a constant in place of d.amt and pass the constant to Filemaker.
I initially was drawing the pie chart using an array format and the onclick worked fine using, d.value.

Is d.amt the correct syntax to use to pass the parameter for the Array of Objects data format?

```
            var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.arc")
                  .data(pie(dataset))
                  .enter()
                  .append("g")
                  .attr("class", "arc")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")")
                  .attr("onclick", function(d, i){
                         return "location.href='" + script + "&param=" + d.amt  + "'";

            });
```

Adding the `.on("click", function(d, i) {..` the pie chart did not plot. For the `location.href =` you have `"script&param=" + d.amt;` I need it to be `'" + script + "&param=" + d.amt  + "'";` in case it makes a difference.
This is what I have;

```
                      ...
                      .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")")
                      .on("click", function(d, i) {
                             location.href ="script&param=" + d.amt;
                      };
```

Answer (score 0):

d3's `on` function serves the purpose better:

```
svg.selectAll("g.arc)
  ...
  .on("click", function(d, i) {
    location.href = script + "&param=" + d.amt;
  });
```

`attr` sets the target statically, while creating the elements. `on` determines the target dynamically, when the click occurs.

Apart from that, `d.amt` is correct, and I'd also expect your `attr` variant to work.

Comment: I had edited my original question with the details when I implemented your recommended change. The pie chart did not plot, any suggestions?

Comment: Not rendering sounds like there's a syntax error. Try searching the console (F12) for details. Unfortunately I am on mobile device right now and can't reproduce. But I noticed that I overlooked a final closin bracket that closes the .on( ... **)** function. Added it now. If you copied exactly, start there.

Comment: Will you re-post the corrected on() function, thanks.

Comment: Still trying to get this to work. Using the .on the pie chart is plotting, but when I click on a pie slice I get a "Web page not found" message. 

You are using a different location.href than I had originally used, return "location.href='" + script + "&param=" + d.amt  + "'"; for the the .attr. 
My .attr statement works if I replace d.amt with a constant, say 50, but not with the d.amt.

At the beginning of the code I have, 
var script = encodeURI('fmp://$/{{FileName}}?script=SliceClick'); that I am passing the parameter to, to execute the Filemaker script SliceClick.

Comment: Sorry, haven't been around a while. I updated the code in my answer above. Try that, please. I wasn't aware that `script` is a string variable; that changes things, of course. I still don't think you need those `'` around that. You need those quotes in the `.attr` function because it prints a string parameter into the SVG element. But you don't need it when setting location.href directly.

Comment: I used .on("click", function(d, i) {
    location.href = script + "&param=" + d.amt;
  }); I did not make any other changes, was that what you suggested? When I changed the .on("click"... the chart no longer showed. Did I miss something?